# Category page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a custom wordpress theme ( first time) , I have created below files and they work fine by following [this](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/) tutorial.

```
index.php
header.php
footer.php
single.php
sidebar.php
```

Now issue is when I click on a category name at home page it show me 404 error, I tried to create category.php but still same issue. here is my index.php which I used for category.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
// other html stuff and loop
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have two question:

1. Is it really require to create category.php or can we use index.php for same purpose to show posts from category or tags?
2. If it's require to create category.php, Do I also need to create tags.php and how will I get posts for those?

Comment: A 404 has nothing to do with your template files. WordPress determines whether or not a request is a 404 before it determines which template file to use. In any case, `index.php` will act as a catchall if `category.php` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not required to have `category.php` file in a WordPress theme. You can see following link for finding out template hierarchy in WordPress works.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category

You can see that, if there is no `category.php` file in theme, it ultimately falls back to `index.php`.